# ionic add ngCordova not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bower

[image: Error Image]

I have tried both command to install `ionic-platform-web-client` but i am not able to install it, it gives me an error kindly refer attached image for same

commands:

```
ionic add ionic-platform-web-client
```

and

```
bower install ionic-platform-web-client
```

I wanted to install following plugins.

```
ionic add ngCordova
ionic add ionic-service-core
ionic add ionic-service-push
ionic add angular-websocket
```

Comment: follow this [steps](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/) , worked without problem for me many times.

Comment: @Vanojx1 Getting same error

Comment: Additional error details:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=No error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [ngCordova File](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/archive/master.zip) from here and Include ng-cordova.js or ng-cordova.min.js in your index.html file before cordova.js and after your AngularJS / Ionic file

Then, include ngCordova as a dependency in your angular module

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])
```

Comment: Your answer is working for ngCordova, what about, ionic add ionic-service-core
ionic add ionic-service-push
ionic add angular-websocket

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
bower install ngCordova --save
bower install ionic-service-core --save
bower install ionic-service-push --save
bower install angular-websocket --save
```